# Confusion waking laptop from sleep/hibernate

Tags: boot, windows-10, laptop, sleep, hibernate

I have a HP Pavilion x2 laptop. It was originally on W8.1 now W10. Both cases, the same problem remains in that when we try to open the laptop we get problems.

Typically it won't appear to do anything after opening so we press the power button and feel it vibrate to know something has happened. Often nothing happens though so we end up pressing it a few times and inevitably the laptop finally comes on, but from a total reboot - because we can't tell what's happening I guess we're rebooting it by accident.

Sometimes detaching the screen (it works as a tablet) lets us turn it on and then re-dock, other times it can take a few minutes to get it to turn on! I've looked at the power and lid/button settings already so can anyone offer some good advice how to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by *"feel it 'buzz' to show something has happened"*, specifically the *buzz* part? Have you installed all HP updates and Windows updates for this laptop? Has this ever worked as expected?

Comment: It simply vibrates to indicate something has happened, similar how to how many phones buzz slightly when you press soft-keys.

Comment: How about the other questions I asked?

Comment: Appears you aren't the only one with the issue. Have you searched the [HP support forum](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Boot-and-Lockup/Windows-10-updated-now-HP-Pavilion-won-t-wake-up-from-sleep/td-p/5176160)?